# Google Map Marker not working

Tags: android, google-maps, data-binding, kotlin, marker

recently i found "FusedLocationApi" is deprecated, so i try fix my apps regarding google doc. my code working fine, and my activity get location, but when i try to set marker, it's not working. i'm so confuse, can anyone help me to find where i missing ?

Here my code.

```
class DealerMapsActivity : FragmentActivity(),
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private val TAG = "DealerMapsActivity"
private var mMap: GoogleMap? = null
private var mGoogleApi: GoogleApiClient? = null
private lateinit var binding: ActivityDealerMapsBinding
private var myLastLocation: Location? = null
private var myMarker: Marker? = null
private var mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreate")
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_dealer_maps)
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
}
```

in this case i use LocationCallback to get location.

```
private var mLocationCallback: LocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {

        for (location in locationResult!!.locations) {
            Log.i(TAG, "accuracy: "+ location.accuracy + " Location: " +
                    location.latitude + " " + location.longitude)
            myLastLocation = location
        }
        SetMapMarker()
        if(myLastLocation!!.accuracy > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "set accuracy into text: "+ myLastLocation!!.accuracy)
            binding.vAccurate.text =
                    "Accurate to "+myLastLocation!!.accuracy.toInt().toString()+ " meters"
        }
    }

}
```

and here my code to set Map Marker.

```
fun SetMapMarker(){
    Log.i(TAG, "set marker")
    if(myMarker != null){
        myMarker!!.remove()
    }
    val latlng = LatLng(myLastLocation!!.latitude, myLastLocation!!.longitude)
    if(myMarker == null){
        myMarker = mMap!!.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latlng)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
        )
    }
    myMarker!!.snippet = "ok"
    myMarker!!.title = "i'm here"

    val camera = CameraPosition
            .builder()
            .target(latlng)
            .zoom(16.0F)
            .build()
    mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camera))
}
```

}

Comment: Have you check  myMarker!!.remove()  statement is setting myMarker as null ? If no then you have to set  null.

Comment: ya, i remove my marker, because i want update my marker position, as you see, after i remove my marker i set my marker again if mymarker == null

Comment: Have you check control go inside if(myMarker == null){   condition ?

Comment: Instead of removing marker you can update marker position using marker.setPosition(latlng)

Comment: wow,, it's working, thankyou @JRamesh, you save my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @J Ramesh suggest, very funny. i just replace with this.

```
fun SetMapMarker(){
val latlng = LatLng(myLastLocation!!.latitude, myLastLocation!!.longitude)
Log.i(TAG, "set marker")
if(myMarker != null){
    myMarker!!.position = latlng
}

if(myMarker == null){
    myMarker = mMap!!.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latlng)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
    )


// you can set title and message only one time not required all time (if you want to change message every time then write these line outside if statement)
 myMarker!!.snippet = "ok"
 myMarker!!.title = "i'm here"
}

val camera = CameraPosition
        .builder()
        .target(latlng)
        .zoom(16.0F)
        .build()
mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camera))
}
```

hope help someone.